# FLUTTER [!] No podspec found for `helloworld` in `Pods/.symlinks/plugins/helloworld/ios`

Tags: dart, cocoapods, flutter

I've been using flutter for a while now. And one time when I went to compile I just got this error. doesn't seem to be anything with my code. I've attempted to reinstall my cocoapods, but that didn't change anything. Anyone have any ideas?

```
  Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Skipping compilation. Fingerprint match.
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (`arm64`)

Finding Podfile changes
  A helloworld
  - Flutter
  - camera

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Pods/.symlinks/flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `camera` from `Pods/.symlinks/plugins/camera-0.1.2/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `helloworld ` from `Pods/.symlinks/plugins/helloworld/ios`
[!] No podspec found for `helloworld ` in `Pods/.symlinks/plugins/helloworld/ios`

/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:85:in `titled_section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:685:in `fetch_external_source'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:661:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:660:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:660:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:659:in `fetch_external_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:82:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone X.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a dependency in my .yaml file.
It's all working now :) I'll leave this here in case anybody goes looking for the same kind of error

Answer (score 6):

This issue has happened to me because I had to rename the plugin I was developing. The package name got taken (for example, `plugin_oldname`) after I started developing the plugin but before I was able to upload.

The solution for me was:

**Fix the `.podspec` name:**

```
  mv ios/plugin_oldname.podspec ios/plugin_newname.podspec
```

**Fix the `s.name` parameter's value in the `podspec` file and replace the `plugin_oldname` with `plugin_newname`.**

```
  Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    # Changed to plugin_newname from plugin_oldname
    s.name             = 'plugin_newname'
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved half of my issue, not I'm getting same problem on different plugin that I've used in my example. How can I fix that ?

[!] No podspec found for `permission_handler` in `.symlinks/plugins/permission_handler/ios`


and what do you mean by s.name ?

Comment: @EmreAkcan I added some clarifications about the s.name. It's in the podspec file, open it and edit its value

Comment: Not sure how to help with your issue, try fixing the s.name first, then maybe try cleaning the caches, build files, etc. Apart from these things, I'm not sure how I can help you